# Как разбить большой файл angular на много файлов, при этом оставаясь в одном классе?

Tags: typescript, angular2, angular

В c# есть partial classes и можно в одном классе держать много данных, которые будут в разных файлах.
Почему я не хочу создать подклассы и вложить их?-  потом сложно будет взаимодействовать по иерархии  верх-вниз.  А в Typescript и Angular я не нашёл такого, как мне огромный файл разбить на части так, как буд-то все методы находятся в одном месте.
Подскажите, как подобное реализовать?
Вычисления в сервисе делаю.
Либо перефразирую понятней- функций очень много- нужно структурировать на части, но если я вложу одну часть в другую, то у меня по структуре один дочерний элемент будет ссылаться на функции другого дочернего или родительского- вообщем так я сделать не могу. Все функции как-бы в одной сущности, хоть и частично можно их поделить на части, но не делать вложенные классы- иначе с пробросом на уровни "выше-ниже" я окончательно запутаюсь

Comment: Я думаю нужно вам делить на компоненты, а потом либо методы перепробрасывать (что не очень хорошо), либо вызывать с дочерних компонентов у родительского методы.

Comment: @"Виталий Шебаниц" ну вот этот вариант я,как раз, хочу избежать, так как у меня структура будет туда-сюда с одного места запустить функцию в другом месте, а потом ещё где-то и так далее. Я вывел вычисления в сервис, но теперь там много функций и их нужно бы как-то легко поддерживать